# Android Studio FirebaseAdapter retrieving of multiple data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `FirebaseAdapter` going on which is suppose to retrieve my Firebase data into a RecyclerView but with these codes, there are no error and nothing on the Logcat but the page is empty when i run. Did i write something wrong?

ExpenseReceiptHistoryFragment

```
        final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Mavis").child("Scan").child(userId);


    receiptHist = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.receiptHist);
    receiptHist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    receiptHist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ExpenseReceiptHistory, ExpenseReceiptHistoryFragment.ReceiptViewHolder>(ExpenseReceiptHistory.class, R.layout.fragment_expense_historyrow, ReceiptViewHolder.class, mdatabase) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ExpenseReceiptHistoryFragment.ReceiptViewHolder viewHolder, ExpenseReceiptHistory model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setAccount(model.getAccount());
            viewHolder.setAmount(model.getAmount());
            viewHolder.setCategory(model.getCategory());
            viewHolder.setCompany(model.getCompany());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
        }
    };
    receiptHist.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

ReceiptViewHolder

```
public static class ReceiptViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public ReceiptViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setAccount(String account){
        TextView paymentText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.paymentText);
        paymentText.setText(account);

    }

    public void setAmount(String amount){
        TextView amountText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.amountText);
        amountText.setText(amount);

    }

    public void setCategory(String category){
        TextView categoryText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText);
        categoryText.setText(category);
    }

    public void setCompany(String company){
        TextView companyText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.companyText);
        companyText.setText(company);
    }

    public void setDate(String date){
        TextView dateText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        dateText.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include log information showing you are getting model data and it is correctly being set in the adapter.

Comment: Please add you database structure.